# XSLT 1.0 Template Returning an Element Empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to have a template call another template that creates a simple XML node with a plain value.  My real tasks is hard but I simplified to just get something working.

Note: I've seen some examples here but I don't get the same results, I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I want to end of with this:

```
<keyword>abc-company.com</keyword>
<keyword>test</keyword>
<keyword>ABC Company</keyword>
```

but I keep ending up with this:

```
<keyword>abc-company.com</keyword>
<keyword/>
<keyword>ABC Company</keyword>
```

I am purposely returning a plain string value, but eventually I want to pass in a value, change it and return a value for the  elements but I simplified it for this example.

```
<xsl:template name="keywords">
    <xsl:param name="metas_branding"/>
    <xsl:param name="metas_keywords"/>
    <xsl:param name="ad_branding"/>
    <keyword><xsl:value-of select="$metas_branding"/></keyword>
     <xsl:call-template name="csvToNodes">
             <xsl:with-param name="csvString" select="$metas_keywords"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <keyword><xsl:value-of select="$ad_branding"/></keyword>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="csvToNodes">
    <xsl:param name="csvString"/>
    <xsl:element name="'keyword'">
            <xsl:value-of select="test"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please always post a **reproducible** example - see [mcve].

Comment: In particular, we need to see the input document.

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Please start a new question with your radically different  requirements. Make sure to include an example of your XML input and a **complete** stylesheet that can be executed as is - something you have failed to provide here, despite being asked several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="test"/>
```

is looking for a an element name `test`, child of the current element. I guess your XML does not have such element (or perhaps it does, but it's empty), so the returned value is an empty string.

You probably meant to write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'test'"/>
```

Comment: Ok, that helped but it still isn't what it should be.  I get this as a result of that change.

`code`

    <keyword>abc-company.com</keyword>

    <keyword/>test

    <keyword>ABC Company</keyword>

`code`

Comment: I don't think so. That's the result you got before, isn't it? So how did that help, exactly? I suspect you did get the correct result, then made some change that took you back.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't figured out the mini-markdown yet.   The difference is the keyword element is still closed without a value, and the test value is placed after it.

Comment: No, that's not what's happening - see: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxM Note that `<xsl:element name="'keyword'">` is invalid.